# Hosting Codeigniter web page in subfolder produces error with models

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I wanted to show my customer the look of new web page, that's why i have uploaded it online in subfolder called /demo/ 
When i visit url www.mypage.com/demo i get following error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Model_services
Filename: /var/www/vhosts/mypage.com/httpdocs/demo/system/core/Loader.php
Line Number: 314
Backtrace:
File: /var/www/vhosts/mypage.com/httpdocs/demo/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Everything is working when i'm working localhost, so that's why i assume that the problem is maybe in .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|img|css|fonts|pdf|scss|uploads|less|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ demo/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have already configured my config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mypage.com/demo/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

autoload.php file

```
$autoload['model'] = array('model_services' => 'ms', 'Model_categories' => 'mc', 'Model_picture_categories' => 'mpc', 'Model_pictures' => 'mp', 'Model_news' => 'mn');
```

Model_services.php

```
class Model_services extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    //Model services functions   
}
```

Folder structure
[image: Folder structure]

I hope some one can help. If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the code that's loading the model?

Comment: i think autoload.php does since webpage is initializing. I have added my autoload.php in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it by my self. There where two problems.
- First one was that my model files started with lower case letter. Looks like WAMP server handles this OK, but when it comes to "real" server, then this is an issue.
- Second problem was that my session folder `system/libraries/session` started with lowercase letter
After changing it in to upper case, my web page started to work.

Answer (score 1):

try doing the autoloading this way in case you made a naming mistake

```
$autoload['model'] = array('Model_pictures', 'Model_news');
```

you can also load a model directly in your controller method or in a controller constructor like this:

```
$this->load->model( 'Model_pictures' );
$this->load->model( 'Model_news' );
```